# Is it possible to generate associative array from laravel pluck()

Tags: php, laravel

```
ModalName::pluck('id')->toArray();
```

i want  id to be associative array with certain defined key.
such as 'my_key'=>id in a pluck

Comment: you can do it like `array('my_key'=>'id')`

Answer (score 1):

First of all pluck() return you already an array so no need to call toArray().

Yes you can make it associative by passing another argument on pluck method. Like this

```
$plucked = $collection->pluck('name', 'product_id');
```

sample result

```
['prod-100' => 'Desk', 'prod-200' => 'Chair']
```

please see docs here [source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections)

so in your case

```
ModalName::all()->pluck('id', 'name'); // name = field in your table
```